# post google maps form submit to python

Tags: javascript, python, forms, google-maps-api-3

**startupdate** In both "what-I-get" and "what-I-want-to-get" below, the word `data` should really be `details`, so I am not even getting what I thought and do not understand the function `downloadUrl` at all, apparently. Am I using the wrong utility function? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.
**endupdate**

When I submit the form below (entering 'Brian'), the result I see in the browser address is as follows.

```
http://localhost:8092/click?data=Brian#
```

But I want it to be something like the following, so that my python app processes it. (I am not sure about this exactly, but hopefully you know what I mean.)

```
http://localhost:8092/details.txt?Action=add&data=Brian#
```

Can you tell me how to get the desired result?

My python contains the following.

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/details.txt', Details),
                                     ('/comment', DetailsLog)],
                                     debug=True)
```

My javascript contains the following script for processing a form.

```
var iwform = '<br />'
        + '<form onsubmit="process(this); return false" action="#">'
        + '  <input type="text" name="data" id="idinput" size="31" maxlength="31" tabindex="1"/>'
        + '  <input type="submit" value="Submit"  tabindex="4"/>'
        + '<\/form>';

function process(form) {
        var details = escape(form.data.value);
    var url = "details.txt?Action=add&details="+details;

        downloadUrl(url, function(doc) { });  

        map.closeInfoWindow();
        alert("Your information has been processed.");
      }
```

The function `downloadUrl()` is from [photomunchers.com](http://photomunchers.appspot.com/js/util.js) and is designed (I believe) to replace a deprecated google map's function `GDownloadUrl()`.

Comment: I have placed the script here [link](https://dpaste.de/gNC1), if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that in using the function `downloadUrl()` I inadvertently forgot to load its src in some of my templates.

Thanks,